# [Bug]: ReferenceError: Worker is not defined when testing AppRouter component #13003

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is initially raised on the FaceBook/Jest repo and I am reposting it here to see if the community has any solution for this when testing with Jest.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/13003